# Do Quarkus & MicroProfile supports Confluent Schema Registry Avro Schema?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry, quarkus, microprofile, smallrye-reactive-messaging

Confluent SchemaRegistry not working with Quarkus and MicroProfile

end up with the below error

```
***********ERROR    
Caused by: io.confluent.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required    configuration "schema.registry.url" which has no default value.
```

I try to build a Quarkus kafka consumer application which has to deserialize the avro serializer message available in a kafka topic.when I try to configure the Schema Registry (Confluent`s) as below to deserialize the kafka message using avro, I end up with the exception

Configuration

```
schema.registry.url=http://kafka-exposed:8081

kafka.bootstrap.servers=kafka-exposed:9200

# Configure the Kafka source (we read from it) 
mp.messaging.incoming.test-quarkustest.group.id=demo

mp.messaging.incoming.test-quarkustest.connector=smallrye-kafka

mp.messaging.incoming.test-quarkustest.topic=kafkacollectioncomplex

mp.messaging.incoming.test-quarkustest.value.deserializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer

mp.messaging.incoming.test-quarkustest.value.value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter

mp.messaging.incoming.test-
mp.messaging.incoming.test-quarkustest.value.converter.schemas.enable=true
```

TRIED AS BELOW AS WELL

```
mp.messaging.incoming.test-quarkustest.value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://kafka-exposed:8081
```

```
***********ERROR
Caused by: io.confluent.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration "schema.registry.url" which has no default value.
```

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class ReadKafkaTopic {
    @Incoming("test-quarkustest")
    public CompletionStage<Void> process(KafkaMessage<String, JsonObject> message) {

        JsonObject data= message.getPayload();
        JsonArray array = (JsonArray) data.getJsonArray("skills");
        return message.ack();
    }
}
```

PROPERTIES

```
schema.registry.url=http://kafka-exposed:8081`
kafka.bootstrap.servers=kafka-exposed:9200`

# Configure the Kafka source (we read from it) 
mp.messaging.incoming.test-quarkustest.group.id=demo`
mp.messaging.incoming.test-quarkustest.connector=smallrye-kafka`
mp.messaging.incoming.test-quarkustest.topic=kafkacollectioncomplex`
mp.messaging.incoming.test-quarkustest.value.deserializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer`
mp.messaging.incoming.test-quarkustest.value.value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter`
mp.messaging.incoming.test-quarkustest.value.converter.schemas.enable=true`
```

TRIED AS BELOW AS WELL

```
mp.messaging.incoming.test-quarkustest.value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://kafka-exposed:8081
```

```
***********ERROR
Caused by: io.confluent.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration "schema.registry.url" which has no default value.

ERROR***********************

2019-10-27 19:08:11,974 ERROR [io.sma.rea.mes.imp.ConfiguredChannelFactory] (main) Unable to create the publisher or subscriber during initialization: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer

76  at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:811)

77  at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:624)

78  at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:605)

79  at io.vertx.kafka.client.consumer.KafkaReadStream.create(KafkaReadStream.java:100)

80  at io.vertx.kafka.client.consumer.KafkaConsumer.create(KafkaConsumer.java:74)

81  at io.vertx.reactivex.kafka.client.consumer.KafkaConsumer.create(KafkaConsumer.java:168)

82  at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka.KafkaSource.<init>(KafkaSource.java:51)

83  at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka.KafkaConnector.getPublisherBuilder(KafkaConnector.java:65)

84  at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka.KafkaConnector_ClientProxy.getPublisherBuilder(KafkaConnector_ClientProxy.zig:203)

85  at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.impl.ConfiguredChannelFactory.createPublisherBuilder(ConfiguredChannelFactory.java:145)

86  at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.impl.ConfiguredChannelFactory.lambda$register$4(ConfiguredChannelFactory.java:123)

87  at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1289)

88  at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.impl.ConfiguredChannelFactory.register(ConfiguredChannelFactory.java:123)

89  at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.impl.ConfiguredChannelFactory.initialize(ConfiguredChannelFactory.java:118)

90  at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.impl.ConfiguredChannelFactory_ClientProxy.initialize(ConfiguredChannelFactory_ClientProxy.zig:195)

91  at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)

92  at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)

93  at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)

94  at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.extension.MediatorManager.initializeAndRun(MediatorManager.java:132)

95  at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.extension.MediatorManager_ClientProxy.initializeAndRun(MediatorManager_ClientProxy.zig:100)

96  at io.quarkus.smallrye.reactivemessaging.runtime.SmallRyeReactiveMessagingLifecycle.onApplicationStart(SmallRyeReactiveMessagingLifecycle.java:20)

97  at io.quarkus.smallrye.reactivemessaging.runtime.SmallRyeReactiveMessagingLifecycle_Observer_onApplicationStart_4e8937813d9e8faff65c3c07f88fa96615b70e70.notify(SmallRyeReactiveMessagingLifecycle_Observer_onApplicationStart_4e8937813d9e8faff65c3c07f88fa96615b70e70.zig:51)

98  at io.quarkus.arc.EventImpl$Notifier.notify(EventImpl.java:228)

99  at io.quarkus.arc.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:69)

100     at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.LifecycleEventRunner.fireStartupEvent(LifecycleEventRunner.java:23)

101     at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ArcRecorder.handleLifecycleEvents(ArcRecorder.java:103)

102     at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.LifecycleEventsBuildStep$startupEvent32.deploy_0(LifecycleEventsBuildStep$startupEvent32.zig:77)

103     at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.LifecycleEventsBuildStep$startupEvent32.deploy(LifecycleEventsBuildStep$startupEvent32.zig:36)

104     at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl1.doStart(ApplicationImpl1.zig:161)

105     at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:94)

106     at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.run(Application.java:218)

107     at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(GeneratedMain.zig:41)

108 Caused by: io.confluent.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration "schema.registry.url" which has no default value.

109     at io.confluent.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:251)

110     at io.confluent.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:78)

111     at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.<init>(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.java:105)

112     at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.<init>(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.java:41)

113     at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.configure(KafkaAvroDeserializer.java:50)

114     at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:713)

115     ... 31 more
```

Comment: First, `value.converter`, and its sub-properties are not a Consumer property, so I'm not sure why you'd try it. Similarly `value.converter.schemas.enable` doesn't do anything for Avro because it always has a schema, but again isn't a consumer property

Answer (score 1):

Given the format

```
mp.messaging.[outgoing|incoming].[channel-name].[attribute]=[value]
```

And the attribute `schema.registry.url`, you'd want the following

```
mp.messaging.incoming.test-quarkustest.connector=smallrye-kafka
mp.messaging.incoming.test-quarkustest.connector=kafkacollectioncomplex
mp.messaging.incoming.test-quarkustest.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

# Setup Avro
mp.messaging.incoming.test-quarkustest.value.deserializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
mp.messaging.incoming.test-quarkustest.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
```

Which internally will call `kafkaConfiguration.put(attribute, value)` before creating a new consumer

---

In any case, `JsonObject` doesn't sound an Avro subclass, so you'd have to change your application code as well

Comment: I had tried the suggested changes but still facing the same issue (Caused by: io.confluent.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration "schema.registry.url" which has no default value.)
Wt I want to know is  Quarkus supports SchemaRegistry or not?    When I explored over internet , I came to know,  As we are using the http protpcol to connect to schemaRegistry which is a blocking request and quarkus is working on that how to handle the blocking mechanisym as quarkus follows  reactive non blocking mechanism. Please correct my understanding.

Comment: I haven't yet tried, but might be worth debugging... In any case, Smallrye-Reactive-Messaging supports Kafka. It doesn't need to explicitly support any single (de)serializer, whether blocking or not. You can't override the internal HttpUrlConnection done by the AbstractAvroSerializer class

Comment: @krishkirk I just tested it, and it works as I answered.

Answer (score 0):

For me it works by setting the schema registry url under the kafka key:

```
kafka.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
```